# Issue with text area <link> text

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to display `<link>` text in a html textarea.
Below is the code that I am using to do this.

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#TextArea1').val('hello world  <a>  <link> hello world');
    });
```

Html code:

```
<body style="background-color:#77de6f"> 
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
    <textarea id="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
   </div>
 </form>
</body>
```

Output that gets rendered on chrome browser

[image]

Using code snippet am not getting `<link />` instead its showing up `<link>`.

Code snippet below

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#TextArea1').val('hello world  <a>  <link> hello world');
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="background-color:#77de6f">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <textarea id="TextArea1" cols="20" rows="2"></textarea>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Can someone let me know why there is difference in outputs? and why `<link>` is getting converted to `<link />` in browser?

Comment: I don't see any difference. See this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/tmryw29x/).

Comment: I'm seeing <link> in Chrome. Do you have the same problem in Firefox or IE?

Comment: The code in the first one should not be doing that; are you sure that's the same code that caused that output?

Comment: Your question includes code that does not produce the behavior you claim it does.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add link to appear inside the textarea box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895109/how-to-add-link-to-appear-inside-the-textarea-box)

Comment: Yes its the same code that I am using and its displaying as <link /> in browser ad not in fiddle or by adding a s a code snippet here.

Comment: I donno why it was down-voted.. I would not have asked a question if the code that I wrote works as expected right

Answer (score 1):

`link` is an empty element. (i.e. an element that has no content or closing tag. In XHTML these were represented with the closing slash at the end of the tag.

`a` is not an empty element. There should be content and a closing `a` tag.

So the browser is representing the `link` as an empty tag and the `a` tag as a non-empty tag.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Empty_element

Comment: So can I know how that can be displayed as just <link> in browser (as fiddle is doing)?